# Como utilizar corretamente o styling do pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

#### Código Python

A partir dos exemplos da [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) o seguinte código foi criado:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import webbrowser
import io

def highlight_max(s):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series yellow.
    '''
    is_max = s == s.max()
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in is_max]

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [5,2,4], [3,8,6]], columns=list("ABC"))

# df.style.apply(highlight_max)
df.style.highlight_max(axis=0)
df_html = df.style.render()

# df_html = df.to_html()
print(df_html)


path = os.path.abspath('temp.html')
url = 'file://' + path

with io.open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(df_html)

webbrowser.open(url)
```

#### Estilo

Em que o valor máximo de cada coluna deveria ser grifado, com a função `df.style.highlight_max(axis=0)` ou função personalizada `df.style.apply(highlight_max)`

Mas a função retorna o seguinte estilo **CSS/HTML** (em branco):

```css
<style  type="text/css" >
</style>
```

```html
<table id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0" > 
<thead>    <tr> 
        <th class="blank level0" ></th> 
        <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >A</th> 
        <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >B</th> 
        <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >C</th> 
    </tr></thead> 
<tbody>    <tr> 
        <th id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >1</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >2</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >3</td> 
    </tr>    <tr> 
        <th id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >5</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >2</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >4</td> 
    </tr>    <tr> 
        <th id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0level0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >2</th> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >3</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >8</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >6</td> 
    </tr></tbody> 
</table>
```

Mas na documentação, a função `df.style.render()` deveria retornar o seguinte **CSS/HTML**:

```html
<style  type="text/css" >
    #T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row1_col0 {
             background-color:  yellow;
         }
    #T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row2_col1 {
             background-color:  yellow;
         }
    #T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row2_col2 {
             background-color:  yellow;
         }
         </style>
<table id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0" > 
<thead>    <tr> 
        <th class="blank level0" ></th> 
        <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >A</th> 
        <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >B</th> 
        <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >C</th> 
    </tr></thead> 
<tbody>    <tr> 
        <th id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >1</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >2</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >3</td> 
    </tr>    <tr> 
        <th id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >5</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >2</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >4</td> 
    </tr>    <tr> 
        <th id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0level0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >2</th> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >3</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >8</td> 
        <td id="T_cdda8a98_02f5_11e9_82ee_40b89ae87fc0row2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >6</td> 
    </tr></tbody> 
</table>
```

#### Problema

Como utilizar corretamente o *Styling* do **Pandas**?

Comment: Resolvi, sintaxe errada... `df_html = df.style.highlight_max(axis=0).render()`
Mas deixarei a pergunta aberta se alguém conseguir outras formas ou uma forma melhor de realizar isto.

Comment: Melhor seria que vc respondesse a propria pergunta. Ela é boa. :-)

Comment: Leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sintaxe `df_html = df.style.render()` está errada se `df` não for um *dataframe*, pois o parâmetro de entrada do `Styler` é um *dataframe*.

Então com:

```
df = df.style.highlight_max(axis=0)
df_html = df.style.render()
```

O parâmetro de entrada é um objeto `Styler`, gerando a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'style'

O correto seria passar todos os atributos, métodos e propriedades do objeto de uma vez da seguinte forma:

```
def hover(hover_color="#ffff99"):
    return dict(selector="tr:hover",
                props=[("background-color", "%s" % hover_color)])

custom_styles = [
    hover(),
    dict(selector="th", props=[("font-size", "150%"),
                               ("text-align", "center")]),
    dict(selector="caption", props=[("caption-side", "bottom")])
]
df_html = df.style.set_properties(**{'max-width': '500px', 'font-size': '10pt'}) \
    .highlight_null(null_color='red') \
    .applymap(highlight) \
    .set_table_styles(custom_styles) \
    .render()
```